# Log in to iOS application through google account and get back to application

Tags: ios, google-plus

I need to integrate login with different social media in iOS application. I managed to make user login with his Facebook, Twitter and LinkedIn account. Now I need to make user to login with his google + account. I have followed below url for the same:
https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in

From above url I managed to open the login view on browser but I not getting any callback method and a way to call it so that I can return in to my application.

Please suggest any posible solution for this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using for multiple media integration, it could be issue with your URL scheme, if I'm right you will already have a URL scheme for Facebook/Twitter so add your Bundle Identifier(com.company.appname)by creating a new item under URL schemes under URL types in your pList.

Answer (score 0):

Post your code.

Did you set the delegate to this?

Did you implement the callback method?

It's

```
- (void)finishedWithAuth: (GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
                   error: (NSError *) error
```